# How do I iterate to all the files in HDFS directory using a schell script?

Tags: linux, shell, hadoop, hdfs, sh

I want to write  a shell script which will iterate all files in a HDFS directory and will access each file and will get created_time of each file in a particulary directory.

Initially I prepared a script for Linux File Systems and it was working fine, my shell script to iterate and  to get files according to file created data was like below-

```
for i in /home/user/Downloads/myDIR/*
do
echo $i
tm=$(stat -c %y $i)
echo $tm | cut -c 1-10
tm2=$(echo $tm | cut -c 1-10)
echo $tm2
if [ "$tm2" = "$(date +%F)" ]
then

cp $i /home/user/OutputDir/
echo "Copy Done"
fi

done
```

This script is working fine but when I implement the same logic to HDFS files then it is not working.

I have replaced Linux Path to HDFS like below-

```
for i in `hadoop fs -ls /TestDir
```

But this is not iterating over files in HDFS.

Is there anything which I am missing here ?

Help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace these commands also

1. `stat -c %y $i`
   to 
   `hadoop fs -stat '%y' $i`
2. `cp $i /home/user/OutputDir/` to `hadoop fs -copyToLocal $i /home/user/OutputDir/`

Command list with options for **hadoop-2.7.2**

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

Comment: Also take a note that `hadoop fs` will require an absolute path when working outside from hdfs.

Comment: Thanks for response.
 When I execute hadoop fs -stat -c '%y' $i

Then getting following exception:

Comment: -stat: Illegal option -c
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -stat [format] <path> ...

Comment: Yes I replaced %y to '%y' but still getting same exception

Comment: Yes ..Its working without "-c" ..It is solved now.
Actually I want to copy last created file within a HDFS directory to S3.
But still I am not able to get last created hdfs file using Shell script.

In shell script when I use following then facing some issues:

Comment: for file in $(hdfs dfs -ls /dir)
do
createdTime= $(hdfs dfs -stat '%y' ${file} )
if [ "$createdTime" == "$(date +%F)" ]
then 
 hadoop fs -cp $file s3://BUCKET_NAME/TARGET_DIRECTORY
fi

This script is not working fine ...Its iterating like below

Comment: stat: `supergroup': No such file or directory
stat: `0': No such file or directory

like this

Comment: Note that `hadoop fs` will require an absolute path. so your ${file} should be /dir/${file}. Also note that `hadoop fs -cp $file s3://BUCKET_NAME/TARGET_DIRECTORY` will only work for local filesystem(afaik). You can do first local copy and then move that to S3.